# How can I get back the Windows 7 Classic mode in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI and get the old Start Menu back in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8)

I am using Windows 8 and want to have the classic Windows 7 mode/look.

I tried the Basic mode but it's not the same as the Classic mode. The colors aren't good in the Basic mode.

Comment: Do you mean change the start menu to class? There is nothing called classic mode in general, either in windows 7 or vista...

Comment: You mean `windows classic visual style`?

Comment: @tumchaaditya What I want is personalize > Aero themes | Classic mode

Answer (score 6):

- If you want the start menu back, its gone for good, there is nothing that you can about it.
- If you are trying to change the control panel to classic mode, that is also not possible in windows 8
- If you trying to change the theme (as suggested by you only finding windows basic) then you can simply copy the classic theme file from windows 7 over, and it will work just fine (themes are basically just a zip archive with images anyway)

Comment: actually you can get start menu using `Stardock Start8` or `Classic Shell`...not the exact solution but wayyy better than start screen

Comment: @tumchaaditya question update

Answer (score 3):

There is no (known) built-in way to get back the Start Menu or "classic mode," but you can try:

1. [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/), which will give you a start menu and allow you to bypass the Metro Start Screen altogether, but it won't altogether disable Metro, since you'll still be able to access the charms bar and the Metro task switcher.
2. You can use [this Classic Shell skin](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1072083-classic-shell-skin-to-get-windows-7-lookalike-start-menu-button/) to get a close-enough replica of the Windows 7 Start Menu back.
3. Or, if you just want to do away completely with Metro, you can use [this](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1091045-windows-7-explorer-for-windows-8/) trick to use the Windows 7 shell file in Windows 8, which will basically send you right back to the Windows 7 experience, BUT REMEMBER TO READ THE "PLEASE READ" SECTION OF THAT POST to know just what you're getting yourself into :D