# Get Windows 8 to Look Like Windows 7

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI and get the old Start Menu back in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8)

Is there a way to get the traditional Windows view on Windows 8 (ie. with the start button and desktop icons).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/).  You can choose between Classic (Windows 2000), XP, or Windows 7 themes.  This will change the Start Menu, Explorer, and Internet Explorer 9.  To disable the Metro lock screen, hit Windows key + R and enter `gpedit.msc`.  Go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization and double-click on "Do not display the lock screen" in the right pane.  Select "Enabled," then click "Apply" and reboot.  Now type `Task Scheduler` into the start menu.  Click "Create Task" in the Actions pane.  Type a name and select "Windows 8" in the "Configure for" drop-down menu.  Click the "Triggers" tab and select "New."  In the dialog, select "On a schedule" from the "Begin the task" drop-down.  Click "OK" and select the "Actions" tab.  Once again, select "New."  In Program/script, type `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`.  Click "OK."  Now if you are on a laptop, click the "Conditions" tab and deselect "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" item.  Click "OK" and the task will be created.  Now reboot and you will see your complete new Windows 7 UI!