# Start button for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-in-windows-8)

I totally miss the Start button on Windows . Is there a way to imitate or get functionality just like of Windows 7 Start button in Windows 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to have to use a third party app. Stardock's [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/) and [Pokki](https://www.pokki.com/) are two such apps which provide a 'replacement' start button for Windows 8

Start8:

[image]

Pokki:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Been using [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net) for a long time now to fix some of the annoyances in Windows 7, and now it works great with Windows 8 as well!

[image]

Comment: Hi @Karan, I also use free Classic Shell too! But the start button not showed when Windows 8 starts for the first time. I have to start Classic Shell application once to have the button. Do you have the same issue? How to get the button auto added at start up?

Comment: @NamG.VU: Worked fine for me last time I checked. Which version of CS are you using? Are you booting straight to the desktop? You might want to ask the developer over in the [forum](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/) so your issue can be debugged properly, perhaps with logs you provide.

Comment: I use version 3.6.7 the latest for now. I'm not booting straight to desktop. How to get that?

Comment: @NamG.VU: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/606095/138343).

Comment: I tried but the issue remained.

Comment: I would go for Okki Menu http://alternativeto.net/software/pokki-menu/

Comment: At this point of course there are several alternatives. You should use whatever works best for you.