# How can one get rid of the MetroUI in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-in-windows-8)

Well as you can see after booting you'll get MetroUI with all those live tiles.Is there any way to get rid of the MetroUI ? I actually love those.But this question is for those who don't like the new UI.Is there any option to disable it ?