# Can I configure Windows 8 to just use the Desktop and remove Metro as an option

Tags: windows-8, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-in-windows-8)

One of the single most annoying things for me is the Metro interface.

Can I remove it entirely and still have a usable Windows 8 machine?

Comment: No, Metro (or as it's now know, Modern UI) is an integral part of Windows 8. It's possible to use a script to switch you to desktop when you're logged in, but you'll still have the two sidebars when you mouse over the corners and you'll probably need to use the start screen to search for settings/apps.

My advise is to give it a try. Modern UI is really great once you get used to it.

Comment: God no - I have tried and it is the single most hateful GUI I have ever had to use. I plan on never using it if at all possible!

Comment: I use it on all my computers, and it is a great desktop/laptop GUI for me. I use the start screen just like I used the start menu back in Windows 7. I press `WIN + search query` to search for apps, or I just press `WIN` and click it, since I've organized them. To search for settings it's `WIN + W`.

Comment: Heh-  I'm beginning to feel like a dinosaur. Tbh I set my win 7 to act like XP to avoid context menus and all those occasions where the OS decides a behaviour for me: )