# Disable associations for Modern UI apps in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Is there any way to completely remove associations set for Modern UI apps in Windows 8 (like opening webpages, files, etc.)?

Comment: what specifically 'prefers' metro applications?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: as I've said, associations are set for metro apps. Webpages, music, video, etc.

Comment: See also: [How do I turn off Modern UI in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-in-windows-8)

Comment: @slhck IMO this is not what is asked here. Asker wants to remove associations between e.g. .mp3 and Media Player, not remove the entire Modern UI app suite?

Comment: @HenningKlevjer This is why I said, "see also". The title and the initial body of the question were very different and it would have been a duplicate then.

Comment: @slhck Right, I can see from the edit history. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the **Set Default Programs** option in the control panel.

To access this, press **Win + W** and enter **Set Default Programs**, now you can go through the programs and apps installed and use the **Choose defaults for this program** to enable and disable different default programs.

---

For example, you can set the *mailto* protocol to use Windows Live Mail (or another email client) by selecting it for the application you want.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to get Windows 7 instead.

Otherwise, you can try [this](http://downloads.pcauthority.com.au/article/28076-skip_metro_suite)

Comment: This answer makes no sense, the user is using Windows 8, using Windows 7 isn't a realistic solution.