# Use Desktop in Windows 8 without Start menu?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-in-windows-8)

The actual question - how do you guys use Desktop without Start menu?

I cant use it because most of my activities is to open programs from programs menu or access shortucts like Control panel.

Now I have to switch back to Windows 8 Start with 'apps' and then run something I need and then back if I need desktop.

And control panel is accessible from desktop only (am I correct?). And so on..

So.. I dont know anymore how to effectively use Windows as a desktop OS (Office, Visual Studio etc).

Can someone offer a viable idea how desktop users must now adapt to the situation (spending hours of flipping through defferent screens is not an option - I already have Android - this is why I dont use it more than just reading and video on a go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider a Start Menu replacement. That's what I did. Lifehacker has several suggestions here: http://lifehacker.com/5955089/how-to-bring-back-the-start-menu-in-windows-8

I'm currently trying out Pokki: https://www.pokki.com/windows-8-start-menu - I like it so far, but the speed could be better.

Answer (score 2):

As for me I don't really notice much of a change. My usual workflow for using the Start menu was

- Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd> key
- Type program name (or part of it)
- Hit <kbd>↲</kbd>

And it works exactly the same with the Start screen in Windows 8. Programs I require frequently during the day are pinned to the task bar which makes launching them as simple as <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (or <kbd>2</kbd>–<kbd>4</kbd>).

I don't usually mess around in the control panel ten times a day, but if I did I would probably have it pinned to the task bar too.

On one thing you are half-right, though: The control panel exists in both the Desktop and Modern modes, but some settings are only accessible from one of the two, some are accessible from both.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot to the traditional desktop (but it is rather complicated):

The following script with launch the desktop:

```
[Shell]
Command=2
IconFile=Explorer.exe,3
[Taskbar]
Command=ToggleDesktop
```

If you save this to an `.scr` file and then set up a task to run this script when you log on you will be automatically switched to the desktop.

[source](http://blog.laptopmag.com/6-ways-to-totally-avoid-metro-and-use-only-desktop-mode-in-windows-8/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can pin your most used applications to the taskbar:

- either right-click the application icon when it's running and select "Pin this program to taskbar"
- or go to Start Screen, right click on the tile of a desktop application you want to pin, and choose "Pin to taskbar" from the bottom menu

This way, you will have to switch to the Start Screen much less often.