# Where did the start menu go?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-in-windows-8)

Where is the start menu in windows 8? The closest I can get is pressing Win + X but that does not bring up the full start menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start menu has been removed in Windows 8 and it was been replaced with a start screen. If you would like the start menu back I would recommend these:

- [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/)
- [ClassicShell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/)