# Have Start button back in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI and get the old Start Menu back in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8)

Is it possible to make start menu open by "Start" button in Windows 8?

Interface when some popup appears when mouse is in the corner not always works and hence not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Install [ClassicShell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/files/), go to the ClassicShell options and select that clicking the StartButton opens the new Windows Startscreen (or the old Startmenu if you still prefer it).

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at Start8, although this is not free at $5. If you want a free program ClassicShell is probably the way to go.