# Windows 8 to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI and get the old Start Menu back in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8)

I have a windows 8 and I certainly don't like it. Is there a way to change a setting for it to go back to the old (best) Windows 7 mode? No tiles and same explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of apps that allow you to get 'regular' Start button in Windows 8 and boot directly into 'regular' desktop.

[Classic Shell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/)

[Pokki](http://www.pokki.com/windows-8-start-menu)

[Stardock Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/)

[power8](http://code.google.com/p/power8/)

[BringBack](http://www.revel-software.it/BringBack.aspx)

And I'm sure I'm missing many other similar apps...
Each of them have their own take on the 'regular' Start button plus most have some additional features.

Comment: Its funny how Windows 7 and 8 cost the same price. Even the workers know that W8 is not that great. I don't get Microsoft, Windows XP=good, Windows Vista=bad, Windows7=good, Windows8=bad. I hope next windows product of OS is good.

Comment: While everyone has their opinions I completely disagree that Windows 8 is bad.  Windows 8 is great for what it was designed for, and that is touch screen computing.  If you've added Win 8 to an older non-touchscreen desktop or laptop then I would say that it is true it is not showing forth its best foot, but it is still very good.  And like every new iteration of Windows, there are issues to be worked out that will get much better over time, such as driver support.  I added Win8 to a 6 year old Pentium D HP laptop and aside from the sound not working some of the time it does an excellent job.