# How to get the old Windows 10 Start menu back

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z46MH.jpg

I recently got a new laptop. My old laptop, running Windows 10, had a really nice Start menu. The buttons for "File Explorer", "Settings", "Power", and "All apps" were big and easy to click (first image).

My new laptop has a fresh install of Windows 10 (second image). I find I have to search for the right icon with the small buttons, and I find the Start menu is cluttered with the apps list there and not in a sub-menu.

Is there any way to get the old one back? I have looked through the settings but I haven't found anything relevant. Googling the issue just shows "how to get the windows 7 start menu in windows 10".

**Good:**
[image]

**Bad:**
[image]

## Edit:

It has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8) question. I am willing to install third-party software to fix this, but I don't want to pay for a piece of software for something so simple.

Comment: What you want requires the use of third-party software.

Comment: @Ramhound How is this in any way a duplicate of that? That was windows 8's god-awful fullscreen start screen!

Comment: 90% of those applications have versions designed for Windows 10, for example (StartIsBack) StartIsBack++ and (Start 8) Start 10 and ClassicShell

Comment: ClassicShell is free....

Comment: It's almost always better to accommodate the current update of OS. World changes, and sometimes we'd better to follow the standards they give us.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is the [new start menu of Windows 10 Version 1607. Here MS placed the programs groups (A-Z) on the left side](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/).

[image]

> We have merged the most used apps list and the All apps list into a
>   single view and elevated it to the top level of the UI to reduce
>   clicking and scrolling. You can now access all your apps with one
>   click on the Start menu. We have also moved important functionality
>   such as Power, Settings, and File Explorer so that they are always
>   visible in the left rail in the Start menu, and updated the Recently
>   added section so that it will now show 3 entries instead of just 1,
>   and can be expanded to see the entire list of new apps.

Currently there is no way to change this.

Add more apps/programs (pin to Start) to the start and click on the right border and make the startmenu larger to see what you had before.

Starting with [Build 14942](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14942-for-pc/), there is an option in the settings app to disable the app list `Hide app list in Start menu`:

[image]

Now the list is gone:

[image]

So you have to install at least the Windows 10 Creators Update or newer (v1703 - Build 15063) to get this option to hide the list.

Comment: You can change it.  The author can use one of the many start menu programs that were created for Windows 8 that also support Windows 10.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have no idea as I use StartIsBack++ on every Windows 10 system I use.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to achieve is mainly a larger tile area, you can treat the start menu like other windows and pull on the right edge to increase the tile space. The top edge is also adjustable.