# How to remove (or customize) the "all apps" in start menu on Windows 10, after the last update (Version 1607, OS Build 14393.82)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Since the last Windows 10 update, all my apps are displayed on Start Menu.

[image]

Before the update, this wasn't displayed like that. I want to remove this section or customize it: for example display all recent apps, or only chosen apps, or something like that. Is that possible?

The current version of Windows I have is:

Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 1607
OS Build 14393.82

Comment: You can't.  At least not without third-party software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove / hide the "All Apps" shortcut from the Start Menu --- or uninstall them totally](http://superuser.com/questions/970609/remove-hide-the-all-apps-shortcut-from-the-start-menu-or-uninstall-them)

Comment: You might prefer the 'Use Start full screen' setting, possibly combined with 'Show more tiles'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the old Windows 10 Start menu back](http://superuser.com/questions/1116919/how-to-get-the-old-windows-10-start-menu-back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the [new start menu of Windows 10 Version 1607. Here MS placed the programs groups (A-Z) on the left side](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/).

[image]

> We have merged the most used apps list and the All apps list into a
>   single view and elevated it to the top level of the UI to reduce
>   clicking and scrolling. You can now access all your apps with one
>   click on the Start menu. We have also moved important functionality
>   such as Power, Settings, and File Explorer so that they are always
>   visible in the left rail in the Start menu, and updated the Recently
>   added section so that it will now show 3 entries instead of just 1,
>   and can be expanded to see the entire list of new apps.

In V1607 (Build 14393) there is no way to change this.

Starting with [Build 14942](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14942-for-pc/), there is an option in the settings app to disable the app list `Hide app list in Start menu`:

[image]

Now the list is gone:

[image] [image]

So you have to install the Windows 10 Creators Update to get this option to hide the list.